# Searching withing a page

Tags: javascript, html

A page has a lot of divs with the class "search-template-block" when I try to search and enter for example a letter "D", the whole "search-template-block" div will be hidden as intended if I try to enter a letter "C" it not be hidden as it can be found in the "template-text" div as intended, but when I search with a letter "A" or "B" the div will not be hidden because it can find this letters inside "buttons-block-text-1,2,3" and "buttons-block-logo" divs.

Is there a way to ignore the "buttons-block-text-1,2,3" and "buttons-block-logo" divs, but at the same time hide the whole "search-template-block" div?

```
function search_chat_template() {
    let input = document.getElementById('searchbar').value
    input = input.toLowerCase();
    let x = document.querySelectorAll('.search-template-block');

    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        if (!x[i].textContent.toLowerCase().includes(input)) {
            x[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        else {
            x[i].style.display = "";
        }
    }
```

````
<div class="search-template-block">
              <div class="template-block">
                <div class="template-text">C</div>
                <div class="template-buttons">
                  <div class="template-buttons-block">
                    <div class="buttons-block-logo">A</div>
                    <div class="buttons-block-text-1">
                      <a href="#">B</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="buttons-block-text-2">
                      <a href="#">B</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="buttons-block-text-3">
                      <a href="#">B</a></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="template-buttons-block">
                    <div class="buttons-block-logo">A</div>
                    <div class="buttons-block-text-1">
                      <a href="#">B</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="buttons-block-text-2">
                      <a href="#">B</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="buttons-block-text-3">
                      <a href="#">B</a></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="template-buttons-block">
                    <div class="buttons-block-logo">A</div>
                    <div class="buttons-block-text-1">
                      <a href="#">B</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="buttons-block-text-2">
                      <a href="#">B</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="buttons-block-text-3">
                      <a href="#">B</a></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="template-buttons-block">
                    <div class="buttons-block-logo">A</div>
                    <div class="buttons-block-text-1">
                      <a href="#">B</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="buttons-block-text-2">
                      <a href="#">B</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="buttons-block-text-3">
                      <a href="#">B</a></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div> ```
````

Answer (score 0):

If you want to effectively whitelist a particular descendant and only search inside it, navigate to it first before extracting and analyzing the `.textContent`.

```
if (!x[i].querySelector('.template-text').textContent.toLowerCase().includes(input)) {
```

In order to blacklist certain decsendants so as not to search within them (and search through everything else), one approach would be to clone the ancestor (so as not to mutate the DOM on the page), remove all such undesirable elements, then search within it.

```
const blacklistSelectors = ['[class^="buttons-block-text"]', '.buttons-block-logo'];

// ...

const templateBlock = x[i];
const clone = templateBlock.cloneNode(true);
for (const selector of blacklistSelectors) {
  for (const descendant of clone.querySelectorAll(selector)) {
    descendant.remove();
  }
}
templateBlock.style.display = clone.textContent.toLowerCase().includes(input)
  ? ''
  : 'none';
```

Another approach without cloning would be to iterate through the text nodes recursively, while not checking those which have a `.closest` element matching any of the blacklisted selectors.